# Do one thing with multiple button?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

Other used it and it worked but I don't know why, it dosent work for me. When I run this app and click the button, it stops.

This is **Main Activity**:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Button btn_iri;
Button btn_nor;
Button btn_aus;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btn_iri =(Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_iri);
    btn_nor =(Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_nor);
    btn_aus =(Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_aus);


    View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String title = view.getTag().toString();
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,NextActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("title",title);
            MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
        }
    };
    btn_iri.setOnClickListener(listener);
    btn_nor.setOnClickListener(listener);
    btn_aus.setOnClickListener(listener);
}
```

And this is my **NextActivity**:

```
public class NextActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
TextView txt_ttl;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_next);
    TextView txt_ttl=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_ttl);

    Intent intent=getIntent();
    Bundle bundle =intent.getExtras();
    if(intent.hasExtra("title")){
        String title = bundle.getString("title");
        txt_ttl.setText(title);
        Log.i("test","title is : "+title);
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Please, can you provide an exception message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to set tag before getting it

```
String title = view.getTag().toString();
```

try this :

```
btn_iri.setTag("anything")
btn_nor.setTag("anything")
btn_aus.setTag("anything")
```

Comment: its work but it have some problem i want , when i click button the text view get same button name ... is it possible?

Comment: Yes, set tag as button name. Ex. btn_iri.setTag(btn_iri.getText());